# MySQL Query to count values

Tags: mysql

I got a table on my database that contains Book ISBNs and Suppliers:

```
ISBN | Supplier

12345 | iSupply
12345 | disal
13333 | disal
14444 | iSupply
15555 | disal
16666 | emporio
```

I need to make a query that shows the count of ISBN that appears only in one supplier. In this example the query should show:

```
iSupply (1)
disal (2)
emporio (1)
```

since ISBN 12345 appears both on iSupply and disal it should not count.

Is it possible to do that ?

EDIT: I'm trying to use some of the solutions you guys posted but it keeps loading for 5-10 with no results. The database has 100-150k records, is this a problem ? Thank you for answers

Answer (score 1):

Group by the SUPPLIER and get the count of each group. The inner query filters out ISBN that are in multiple SUPPLIERs

```
select supplier, count(*)
from your_table
where isbn not in 
(
    select isbn
    from your_table
    group by isbn
    having count(*) > 1
)
group by supplier
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution. It keeps loading for 5 to 10 minutes with no results. The database has 100-150k records, is this a problem ? Thank you for answers

Comment: Do you have an index on `isbn` and also one on `supplier`? Also using subqueries is problematic on big tables. Did you try @Strawberry's solution?

Comment: Same thing happened.  i got an index on each entry only, named id_tablename

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to see where the keys are not used.

Comment: 1
PRIMARY
precofornecedor
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
119761
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: 2
DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
precofornecedor
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
119761
Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Looks like it does not use any indexes. And it is the same with the other query? It shouldn't. Please add your table definitions to your post along with the EXPLAIN output.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.supplier
     , COUNT(*)  
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.isbn = x.isbn 
   AND y.supplier <> x.supplier 
 WHERE y.isbn IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY x.supplier;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am obviously a bit late with my answer, but it works:

```
SELECT suppl,count(*) cnt FROM tmp
WHERE isbn IN (SELECT isbn FROM tmp GROUP BY isbn HAVING COUNT(*)=1)
GROUP BY suppl
```

The subquery  in the where clause returns only `isbn`s that appear uniquely, then the outer `select` groups together the counts for each supplier.

Yeah, I just looked up and discovered that it is almost the same anser as "juergen d"'s but it was written independently.

Or, "a variation on the theme":

```
SELECT suppl,count(*) cnt FROM tmp t
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 FROM tmp WHERE isbn=t.isbn AND suppl!=t.suppl )
GROUP BY suppl
```

In the end it is a matter of taste. ;-)

Comment: Other than, that my answer is a bit late and maybe not *that* original ... Why the downvote ?!?

Comment: Not my dv, but I suspect it's because of the similarity to answers already provided.